# how to show error_log() in filament-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I trying to debug something in my filament-laravel using error_log('testing..'),
But I can't find the error message in terminal.
The program is running well, form function running well also.

Here is code :

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    error_log('testing..');
    return $form
        ->schema([

            Card::make()
                ->schema([
                    TextInput::make('country_code')
                    ->maxLength(3),
                    TextInput::make('name')
                    ->maxLength(255),

                ]),
        ]);
}
```

Thank. You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel Logging Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/logging#writing-log-messages)

Example

```
Log::info($message);
```

> Read more - [Errors & Logging](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors)

Answer (score 0):

You should use dd().

```php
dd($message);
```

This will show the error log on the page. Very handy for debugging!